# Colocar pasta auth em subpasta (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, aplicação-web, laravel-5

Sou novato em Laravel e no meu projeto quero colocar a pasta da view auth dentro da pasta admin, ficando assim:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\resources\views\admin\auth\
```

Porém, sei que ainda devo editar algo mais nos arquivos Laravel para que o novo caminho auth seja encontrado, mas não sei o que devo alterar.

Versão: Laravel Framework 5.4.36

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui
httpss://stackoverflow.com/q/40110160/4623423

Answer (score -2):

No seu terminal utilizando `php artisan route:list` você sera capaz de ver todas as rotas relacionadas à autenticação do Laravel.

Mudando o diretório das views você também deve mudar todas as chamadas que foram feitas para elas. Em cada controller que fica na pasta `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` é feita uma chamada para cada uma das views da pasta auth.

Para mudar as chamadas, não vejo outra forma a não ser a sobrescrita dos métodos que chamam essas views.

Se não entendeu, da uma olhada [aqui](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-change-the-view-path-of-laravel-54-auth)

Esqueci de mencionar que as chamadas geralmente são feitas em traits que são incluídas com o próprio Laravel e ficam armazenadas na pasta vendor. Você nunca deve modificar códigos direto na pasta vendor, por isso falei e sobrescrever os métodos.